# Redirect all links to subdomain couterpart and define specific redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I need to redirect all links to a new subdomain counterpart *apart* from specific links I define which will direct to new directories in the main website. So for example:

**/mywebsite.com/news/welcome/** –goes to– **/archive.mywebsite.com/news/welcome/**

and then...

**/mywebsite.com/about/** –goes to– **/mywebsite.com/about-our-services/**

EDIT: I also require some links to simply just go to the root of the main domain, so:

**/mywebsite.com/people/** –goes to– **/mywebsite.com/**

The rules below successfully redirect links to the archive subdomain but the **/about** redirect ends up at:

**/archive.mywebsite.com/about-our-services/**

How can I achieve this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about/$ https://mywebsite.com/about-our-services [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^archive\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://archive.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You will need to add a RewriteCond to your second rewrite that checks that the requested URI was _not_ `/about-our-services/`.

Comment: I assume from your rule that the main domain and subdomain point to the same place?